# Multiple default Popup notification for ALL events?

Tags: google-calendar

I'd like to be notified by a popup whenever an event is listed in my calendar.

I can see that Google Calendar has an option to email or SMS me under "Event notifications", but I don't always see my emails, and would like to have a popup notification show instead, at 30 minutes before, and 5 minutes before the event.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Do you keep your Calendar always open on your browser? Are you using the old or the new Google Calendar?

Comment: I can use either or, but was using the new Calendar

Comment: and I don't tend to keep my calendar open all the time, but could consider this

Comment: See [Modify Google Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cturn-notifications-on-or-off)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I've found so far is to subscribe to my Google Calendar in my Mac Calendar, using the process detailed here on Google's Support site:

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

#### In short, the steps to import are:

- On your computer, open Mac Calendar.
- In the top left corner of your screen, click Calendar and then Preferences.
- Click the Accounts tab.
- On the left side of the Accounts tab, click Add Add.
- Select Google and then Continue.
- To add your Google account information, follow the steps on the screen.
- On the Accounts tab, use "Refresh Calendars" to choose how often you want - Apple Calendar and Google Calendar to sync.

#### Now choose when alerts are shown by

- Opening Mac Calendar
- Choose "Preferences | Alerts | Account: Google"
- Choose "Events: At time of event" or whatever you want